# How can I pass data to a bootstrap modal when use angularJS components way

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have 3 components:

1st one for the page display, 
2nd to display a ng-repeat table with the data fetched from the database, 
3rd is a bootstrap modal.

when I click on a cell in the table, the modal pop up and able to edit data from the cell. But I'm not able to pass any data of the cell clicked to the modal. I've checked some asked questions here, but most of them works with $scope. Is there a way to do it when they are components? Any hints or maybe links to existing posts or pages? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please show relevant code. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the part of the code from the link https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

```
$scope.open = function (size) {

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  size: size,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});
here $scope.open(data) will be the click function when you click on the particular cell and pass the data  from the cell to the function and in resolve you can send that data to the modal.
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm you can use a function to bind that specific cell into a model.

e.g.

```
<th>
   <!-- item or whatever you use inside the ng-repeat-->
   <button ng-click="selectItem(item)"
           type="button"
           class="btn btn-xs btn-info"
           data-toggle="modal"
           data-target="#myModal"></button>
</th>
```

in you controller have a function similar to this.

```
$scope.selectItem= function (item) {
        $scope.myItemModal= item;
};
```

and finally in your modal you can use it as a normal `$scope` variable

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        {{myItemModal}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```